# Using function to search tuple in python

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to work out how to write a function that searches a list of tuple pairs and returns the value associated with the first element of the pair.

I so far have got this...

```
def search_list(list_of_tuples,value):
list_of_tuples = for element in prices
    print(element[0])
return list_of_tuples

prices = [('AAPL',96.43),('IONS',39.28),('GS',159.53)]
ticker = 'IONS'
print(search_list(prices,ticker))
```

im looking for it to print
'AAPL'
'IONS'
'GS'

any help appreicated.

Comment: `list_of_tuples = for element in prices` should surely throw a `SyntaxError`. Your indentation is also off, please fix it.

Comment: What errors are you receiving? What is the output you're getting right now?

Comment: Assuming your indentation is correct in your own code, and based on the question just requiring a printed output, I think you just need to get rid of `list_of_tuples = ` and add a colon on the end of `for element in prices:`.

Answer (score 2):

if you just need to print the first element of each:

```
def search_list(list_of_tuples):
    for i in list_of_tuples:
        print(i[0])

prices = [('AAPL',96.43),('IONS',39.28),('GS',159.53)]
search_list(prices)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Loana your answer is exactly where I was trying to get to. That works perfectly.